# How to run node app with sublime text

Tags: node.js, terminal, sublimetext2

How would you run node app with sublime text? Like this, open the file app.js in sublime, go to menu->tools->build, and it just runs. Simple like that

Comment: Solution to this problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127711/sublime-build-how-to-stop-re-build-restart-node-app/12146477#12146477

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run nodejs on sublime text, install node package "node dev" then create a sublime text build, the code should look like this

```
{
  "cmd": ["node-dev", "$file"],
  "selector" : "source.js",
  "path" : "/usr/local/bin"
}
```

Now to run a nodejs app, go to menu->tools->build.

Comment: I simply couldn't find such a plugin, "node dev". On the other hand, "nodejs" was installed without any problems.

Answer (score 19):

Cmd+Shift+P , search for "Nodejs::Default File Settings" ,it will open file "Node.js.sublime-settings". you'll see:

```
{
  // save before running commands
  "save_first": true,
  // if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
  // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
  "node_command": false,
  // Same for NPM command
  "npm_command": false,

  "expert_mode": false,

  "ouput_to_new_tab": false
}
```

modify

**"node_command": false,**

to

**"node_command": "/usr/local/bin/node",**

if the node path is not the same with above, find it and change to yours.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to fix the plugin's path yourself. One option is changing Nodejs.sublime-build. It's located in the packages directory of sublime:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Nodejs/Nodejs.sublime-build 

Linux: ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Nodejs/Nodejs.sublime-build
```

Note: On latest OS X versions the Library folder is hidden. If that's the case, from the menu select Go > Go to Folder... and type ~/Library.

```
Change "cmd": ["node", "$file"] to "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/node", "$file"]

{
  "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/node", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.js",
  "shell":true,
  "encoding": "cp1252",
  "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node", "$file"]
    },
  "linux":
    {
        "cmd": ["killall node; node", "$file"]
    }
}
```

Lastly, open your *.js file and press command + b. Everything should just work fine now.

Linux Users: This file is identical across all operating systems. Finding the path to Nodejs.sublime-build may require running a search. In most cases it's located in ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Nodejs/Nodejs.sublime-build

Answer (score 1):

What is going on is that you don't have the right PATH setup for your terminal.

try this command in a regular terminal:

```
> which node
```

I peronaly get this:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

As you can see this path is not in you environement path to add it in a regular terminal you would edit .bashrc or .bash_profile and add this line

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Here well you just have to look at the [doc](https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs#build-systems) and find out that you need to modify the configuration file.

> If you have a JavaScript file open, by selecting selecting Tools ->
>   Build Systems -> Nodejs and then hitting Ctrl + B, you will activate
>   the node build system on your file and node will try to run it. You
>   may need to add a path variable to the settings object for this if
>   your node executable is not found

Look at [this](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html?highlight=env%20path#troubleshooting-build-systems).

Comment: How could `which node` return something useful since node binary is obviously not in his PATH ?

Comment: Sublime doesn't use the system path.

Answer (score 0):

On xubuntu, I made the build command in Nodejs.sublime-build explicity use the terminal:

"cmd": ["xfce4-terminal",  "--command", "node $file"]

Answer (score 0):

Create a build sytem with this code:

```
{
   "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
   "selector" : "source.js"
}
```

Comment: Would be great to add a description of where to save this json to

Answer (score 0):

First make sure node is installed properly.
Create new build system in sublime.

Tools > Build System > New Build System

It will create new file. replace the content with below comman

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "node $file"
}
```

save the file with extention `.sublime-build`

i.e. node.sublime-build

Now select build system in tools>build system>node (or whatever name you have set)

All set. open js file and hit ctrl+B or go Tools>build