# sublime build - nodejs - how to start and stop node app

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2

So my node build is like this

```
{
  "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
  "selector" : "source.js",
  "path" : "/usr/local/bin"
}
```

It runs, but problem is once it runs, it never stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a reloader like [node-dev](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev) for this kind of thing.

Replace `node` with `node-dev` (`npm install -g node-dev`) and that's it so your build file looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["node-dev", "$file"],
    "selector" : "source.js",
    "path" : "/usr/local/bin"
}
```

I personally use node-dev, but you may also try [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) or [node-nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).

Answer (score 2):

for windows users, use "shell_cmd" instead of "cmd"

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "node ${file}"
}
```

If you need to stop/cancel build, open `"Tools | Cancel Build"`

Answer (score 1):

Putting together all the answers in a step by step:

1) Install node-dev package:

```
npm install -g node-dev
```

2) Create a new Build on your Sublime Text

Tools > Build System > New Build System…

```
{
    "cmd": ["node-dev", "$file"],
    "selector" : "source.js",
    "path" : "/usr/local/bin"
}
```

save the file as **NodeJS.sublime-build**.

3) Open your project, select your new node Build System, and Change your code and save.