# ERROR: The process "node.exe" not found

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2

The Complete error is

```
ERROR: The process "node.exe" not found.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

I am using Sublime text 2, and installed the NodeJS plugin, I tried to run a simple script, it runs fine with alt+r, but when I saved it (ctrl+s) it gave me that. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't have Node installed yet on your Windows machine? If you've already installed it, you can check your PATH variable in System Settings to make sure NODE_PATH is set to the location of your Node install.

EDIT: sorry about that, haven't used node on windows in a while -- travis is right, nodejs.org is best place for install

[Node.js download page](http://nodejs.org/)

Also might be worth checking if nodejs plugin requires 32 or 64-bit version of Node specifically, since they will be installed in different locations.

Comment: I think you're right about @user24454 not having Node installed. However, the article you linked is two years old and a little outdated. The easiest way to install Node on Windows now is to go to http://nodejs.org, click on Install, then run the installer.

Comment: NODE IS INSTALLED ALREADY. READ THE FIRST POST BEFORE CAREFULLY PLEASE.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This is a type of decision: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qW7cseYJu4
This is another: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14097164/1979853