# React Native, TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run my react native app in my physical device but every time I get this error

```
TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
[Mon Oct 26 2020 10:37:19.635]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
[Mon Oct 26 2020 10:37:19.636]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
[Mon Oct 26 2020 10:37:19.637]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

so I try to just render a simple text hello

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But still I'm getting that error, why? can anyone tell me what's happening?

my index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: Have you imported "Component" from "react" or "react-native"?

Comment: yes i imported it from react

Comment: `import React, {Component} from 'react';`

Comment: @Dark Prince Can you share your app.json file

Comment: Please check by removing app.json file from import and use your app name as string like "testApp" there

Comment: @VahidAkhtar ya sure

Comment: `{
  "name": "gopro",
  "displayName": "gopro"
}`

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani ok wait

Comment: @DarkPrince - try this answer and related thread - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304124/7986074

Comment: @DarkPrince Have you tried with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604603/module-appregistry-is-not-registered-callable-module-calling-runapplication/51304124#51304124

Comment: yes I tried it shows `The process "node.exe" not found.`

Comment: @DarkPrince - presuming you are using windows based system - "node.exe" or simply node-js must be there; See if this helps in this context - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621428/error-the-process-node-exe-not-found/

Comment: yup, I'm using windows and it's showing node.exe not found bcoz node server is running

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding a Contructor to the App component, and calling `super(props)`, in the **first line** of the constructor

Comment: I think its issue with the Class Component, I setup the similar project and i didn't have any issues running it. Maybe you can try to change the class component with the functional one, and see if the error persists. Also, can you provide us with the code, so that we can further investigate

Comment: it's not that some packages causing that like gifted chat