# How to get a node or cmd terminal in sublime?

Tags: node.js, npm, sublimetext3

Is there a way to run npm commands from Sublime?

For instance, if I wanted to run `npm install angular-ui-grid` on the current folder in Sublime, how would I do that?

I've looked at [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124544/how-to-run-node-app-with-sublime-text) that say I can build with Node in Sublime, but I don't think that means I can run `npm install` as if I was in a terminal.

I know you can run a Python terminal from Sublime with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, and you can open a [command window at the current location](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminal), but is there any way to combine the two?

NOTE: Looking for a **Windows** cmd or powershell terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are looking for **TerminalView**

This is a Linux/macOS plugin for Sublime Text 3 that allows for terminals inside editor views. The plugin uses a pseudo-terminal to start the underlying shell which means it supports

- Interactive applications
- Auto-completion
- Terminal shortcuts (ctrl+c, etc.)
- Password prompt etc.

You can get this package here,

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TerminalView

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified Windows. I was hoping there was an all-in-one package option.